# Unable to close and reopen Floating Panel in Dojox

Tags: dojo, floating

I am trying to open a floating panel, using onClick event, it opens fine but shows this error in the console, `this.onClick is not a function`.

If I close the floating panel and then try to a reopen, it won't open again and I keep receiving the same error in the console.

This is my [application](http://msgist2011.grd.arizona.edu/project/begin.html). You can see a floating panel emerge when you click on the `Layers` button in the toolbar.

This is the main function that is opening the FLoating Panel,

```
function addFloatingPanel() {
    var fp = new dojox.layout.FloatingPane({
        title: "Layers",
        resizeable: true,
        dockable: false,
        closable: true,
        style: "position:absolute; top:0; left:50px; width:245px; height: 175px; z-index: 100; visibility: hidden;",
        id: 'floater'
    }, dojo.byId('floater'));
    fp.startup();
    if (dojo.byId('floater').style.visibility === 'hidden') {
        dijit.byId('floater').show();
    } else {
        dojo.byId('floater').style.visibility = 'hidden'
        dijit.byId('floater').show();
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Also, the floating panel is visible in firefox but not in chrome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to create the `dojo.connect` function

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="searchTool" >Search</div>
```

for `onclick` event,

```
searchTl = dojo.byId('searchTool');
dojo.connect(searchTl, "onclick", openSrFp);
```

and add this function,

```
var fp = dojo.byId('floater');
            if (fp.style.visibility=="hidden") {
                fp.style.visibility="";
            } else {
                fp.style.visibility="hidden";
            }
```