# Keeping access to the web page even when dijit.dialog appears

Tags: dojo, dom-events

Problem I am facing is that when I activate the `dijit.dialog()`, the web page blurs and I can not connect with the page till I close the dialog box. Is there some way that I can keep the dialog box open and still access the page. By access I mean that the web page should be able to listen to click events or things like that. If not is there some other tool that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `dojox/layout/FloatingPane` because `dijit/Dialog` is quite hard-wired to be modal (via singletons):

```
// var FloatingPane = require("dojox/layout/FloatingPane");
var floatingPane = new FloatingPane({
    title: "FloatingPane",
    content: "Hello World!",
    resizable: false,
    dockable: false
}, "floatingPane");

floatingPane.startup();
```

or if you insist on `dijit/Dialog` you can subclass it, but expect possible weird stuff, esp. when nesting and/or combining modal/non-modal dialogs:

```
// var Dialog = require("dijit/Dialog");
var ModelessDialog = declare(Dialog, {
    show: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        Dialog._DialogLevelManager.hide(this);                      
    }
});
```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/TgEWL/

**N.B.:** Do not forget to include *dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css* and *dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css* stylesheets when using `FloatingPane.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @phusick. I am using the floating pane but I am facing the issue of closing and opening it. I did post this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548488/unable-to-close-and-reopen-floating-panel-in-dojox but did not receive any response so thought creating Dialog and destroying it was easy so went for it but the Modal feature was a problem. Can u help me in how I can destroy the Floating pane widget and reassign new one?